# Use Bash variable within SLURM sbatch script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, slurm

I'm trying to obtain a value from another file and use this within a SLURM submission script. However, I get an error that the value is non-numerical, in other words, it is not being dereferenced.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This reads out the number of procs based on the decomposeParDict                                                                                          
numProcs=`awk '/numberOfSubdomains/ {print $2}' ./meshModel/decomposeParDict`
echo "NumProcs = $numProcs"

#SBATCH --job-name=SnappyHexMesh                                                                                                                            
#SBATCH --output=./logs/SnappyHexMesh.log                                                                                                                   
#                                                                                                                                                           
#SBATCH --ntasks=`$numProcs`                                                                                                                                
#SBATCH --time=240:00                                                                                                                                       
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4000                                                                                                                                  

#First run blockMesh                                                                                                                                        
blockMesh

#Now decompose the mesh                                                                                                                                     
decomposePar

#Now run snappy in parallel                                                                                                                                 
mpirun -np $numProcs snappyHexMesh -parallel -overwrite
```

When I run this as a normal Bash shell script, it prints out the number of procs correctly and makes the correct `mpirun` call. Thus the `awk` command parses out the number of procs correctly and the variable is dereferenced as expected.

However, when I submit this to SLURM using:

```
sbatch myScript.sh
```

I get the error:

```
sbatch: error: Invalid numeric value "`$numProcs`" for number of tasks.
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Don't use backticks inside a script. Use a different one like `$(...)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This won't work. What happens when you run

`sbatch myscript.sh`

is that slurm parses the script for those special #SBATCH lines, generates a job record, stores the batch script somewhere. The batch script is executed only later when the job runs.

So you need to structure you workflow in a slightly different way, and first calculate the number of procs you need before submitting the job. Note that you can use something like

`sbatch -n $numProcs myscript.sh`

, you don't need to autogenerate the script (also, mpirun should be able to get the number of procs in your allocation automatically, no need to use "-np").

Comment: Yes, that's the solution.  I use a "sub" script to submit my job script.  Thanks @Janneb

Answer (score 3):

Slurm stops processing `#SBATCH` directives on the first line of executable code in a script. For users whose `#SBATCH` directives are not dependent on the code they're trying to run above those directives, just put the `#SBATCH` lines at the top.

See the other answer for a workaround/solution if, as with OP, your sbatch options are dependent on the commands you've placed above them.

> The batch script may contain options preceded with "#SBATCH" ***before
> any executable commands in the script***. sbatch will stop processing
> further #SBATCH directives once the first non-comment non-whitespace
> line has been reached in the script.

From the [sbatch docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html), my emphasis.