# Sbatch: pass job name as input argument

Tags: slurm

I have the following script to submit job with slurm:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J $3 #job_name 
#SBATCH -n 1 #Number of processors
#SBATCH -p CA 

nwchem $1 > $2
```

The first argument ($1) is my input, the second ($2) is my output and I would like the third ($3) to be my jobname. If I do like this, the job name is '$3'. How can I proceed to give the jobname as an argument of the script?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The SBATCH directives are seen as comments by the shell and it does not perform variable substitution on `$3`. There are several courses of action:

Option 1: pass the  `-J` argument on the command line:

```
sbatch -J thejobname submission_script.sh input.data output.res
```

Option 2: pass the script through `stdin` replacing the position arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc. by named ones)

```
IN=input.data OUT=output.res NAME=thejobname <submission_script.sh sbatch
```

Option 3: write a wrapper

```
#!/bin/bash
sbatch <<EOT
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -J $3 #job_name 
#SBATCH -n 1 #Number of processors
#SBATCH -p CA 

nwchem $1 > $2
EOT
```

and use it like this:

```
submit.sh input.data output.red thejobname
```

Also note that the second shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) is useless and ignored by the (parent) shell.

Comment: What happens to SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR when you use this approach?

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. I did `sbatch -J $3 run.sh` and it reflected the job name correctly in `squeue`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `srun` along with `sbatch`, you could run a `srun` one-liner within a `sbatch` script. Most of `sbatch` arguments can also be used with `srun`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 1 #Number of processors
#SBATCH -p CA 

srun nwchem -J $3 $1 > $2
```