# bash variable expansion in slurm's #SBATCH directive

Tags: slurm

is it possible to use variable expansion in `#SBATCH` lines in slurm? for instance I want to have line below:

```
#SBATCH --array=0-100%{$1-10}
```

so that by default it uses 10 concurrent job unless I manually pass an argument when I call `sbatch`.

Above gives me an `Invalid job array specification` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line arguments via sbatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708656/pass-command-line-arguments-via-sbatch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. But you can overwrite the scripts default `--array` by giving it explicitly on the `sbatch` command line.