# Import bash variables into slurm script

Tags: slurm

I have seen similar questions, but not exactly the same as mine: [Use Bash variable within SLURM sbatch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508040/use-bash-variable-within-slurm-sbatch-script), because I am not talking about slurm parameters.

I want to launch a slurm job for each of my sample files, so imagine I have 3 vcfs and I want to run a job for each of them:

I created a script to loop through a file in which I wrote sampleIds to run another script with each sample, which would perfectly work if I wanted to run it directly with bash:

```
while read line
do

sampleID="${line[0]}"

myscript.sh $sampleID
```

The problem is that I need to run the script with slurm, so is there any way to indicate slurm the bash variable that it should include?

I was trying this, but it is not working:

```
sbatch myscrip.sh --export=$sampleID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've solved it:

```
sbatch --export=sampleID=$sampleID myscript.sh
```