# SLURM array Add variable in #SBATCH options

Tags: slurm

I have a SLURM array

```
#SBATCH --array=0-1000%10
```

and I need to add a variable instead of "1000"

to be something like

```
#! /bin/bash
num=$1
#SBATCH --array=1-${num}%10
```

or if there is other way to setup the range. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm does not interpret variables in `#SBATCH` lines, and stops looking for `#SBATCH` lines as soon as a non-comment line is found so in your case the `num=$1` line.

One option is to pass that parameter as an argument of the `sbatch` command line

```
sbatch --array=1-${num}%10 submit.sh
```

For more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508040/use-bash-variable-within-slurm-sbatch-script)